# What Chinese characters are rare in modern but common in classical Chinese?

Tags: vocabulary, classical-chinese, database

I browsed randomly through texts written in classical Chinese, and I noticed there were a lot of Chinese characters that were frequent in classical Chinese but never or rarely being present in modern Chinese. 
Some examples:
吾，爾，而，谐，虞，乎,乃，伊，卿，叟，孰，弥 。。。

Could you provide further examples, especially characters which are used lexically?

Comment: These are all pretty common in modern texts, actually.

Comment: sorry, it was not easy to reproduce the characters i ve seen, i did not know their pronounciation, but i will collect them and add to the list.

Comment: Most of them are fixed in idioms and be used today. 爾虞我诈，人非圣贤，孰能无过。童叟无欺。we don't use them separately.

Answer (score 10):

There are people studying this.

[Classical Chinese Character Frequency List](http://lingua.mtsu.edu/chinese-computing/statistics/char/list.php?Which=CL)

[Modern Chinese Character Frequency List](http://lingua.mtsu.edu/chinese-computing/statistics/char/list.php?Which=MO)

Now do your own comparisons because I'm lazy.

---

**Update** -- I feel less lazy today so I'll give it a shot.

For obvious purposes, let't take the first 1000 characters in the classical list and see where they go in the trend. I can't do scripts so I'll do excel. Anyway, here are words that are falling out of favor:

- Ancient date and time system: 甲乙丙丁, 子丑寅卯, etc
- Ancient bureaucracy: 丞, 诏, 诛, 朕, 卿, 吏, 郡, etc.
- Some daily words are also fading away: 吾, 汝, 焉, 哉, 勿, 曰, etc.
- Moral concepts: 孝, 贤, 贞, etc.
- Hard to categorize: 骸, 淮, 朔, etc. Either the concepts are no longer popular, or there are substitutes that is becoming popular....

Answer (score 2):

Based on Wang Dingwei's answer, I ran a quick script on these two files.
Here are the Classical characters that don't appear in the Modern list.

```
C   Class   Modern
鐸   4128    ?
諲   5008    ?
鞶   5488    ?
鉷   5516    ?
鴈   5657    ?
頔   5672    ?
褾   5730    ?
衎   5761    ?
蟽   5789    ?
綯   5817    ?
諴   5851    ?
禼   5872    ?
虓   5877    ?
菶   5892    ?
醔   5893    ?
饍   5934    ?
紞   5962    ?
鞞   5963    ?
翾   6004    ?
臱   6036    ?
鈒   6045    ?
耤   6060    ?
襈   6082    ?
鉨   6083    ?
窴   6106    ?
襚   6133    ?
韡   6182    ?
魨   6183    ?
騑   6193    ?
黁   6208    ?
磝   6237    ?
黓   6245    ?
黙   6246    ?
趫   6254    ?
蒍   6268    ?
鬷   6278    ?
睈   6293    ?
襜   6305    ?
蒱   6306    ?
褭   6331    ?
礩   6386    ?
韐   6422    ?
鹢   6444    ?
磎   6445    ?
祊   6449    ?
鷪   6450    ?
眱   6459    ?
睟   6486    ?
纚   6487    ?
褕   6488    ?
酅   6489    ?
衆   6490    ?
蚃   6498    ?
羖   6505    ?
軨   6506    ?
鄀   6517    ?
脤   6542    ?
礶   6543    ?
薁   6566    ?
簄   6567    ?
闬   6582    ?
醦   6583    ?
駼   6605    ?
謵   6623    ?
餧   6624    ?
矁   6625    ?
莋   6626    ?
矼   6635    ?
諢   6636    ?
銛   6637    ?
釂   6646    ?
軋   6647    ?
鄃   6648    ?
馛   6649    ?
簝   6662    ?
繄   6663    ?
眛   6673    ?
鸑   6685    ?
雝   6699    ?
秏   6717    ?
禟   6718    ?
謜   6729    ?
譊   6730    ?
褷   6731    ?
驲   6745    ?
腯   6762    ?
碏   6773    ?
螾   6774    ?
菻   6775    ?
蚄   6792    ?
浈   6793    ?
齎   6794    ?
   6795    ?
禴   6814    ?
绬   6815    ?
虸   6816    ?
饎   6835    ?
躧   6836    ?
觷   6837    ?
芚   6852    ?
藟   6853    ?
釴   6854    ?
膎   6855    ?
鈮   6856    ?
髩   6857    ?
鮧   6872    ?
盭   6891    ?
膢   6892    ?
韎   6893    ?
鹥   6894    ?
絇   6905    ?
讗   6906    ?
鉶   6907    ?
顥   6908    ?
紒   6929    ?
蒢   6930    ?
絰   6942    ?
萯   6943    ?
謷   6944    ?
麛   6945    ?
笴   6964    ?
絻   6965    ?
臝   6966    ?
黈   6967    ?
鼛   6968    ?
紥   6969    ?
駆   6970    ?
鹴   6971    ?
纼   6988    ?
轜   6989    ?
隮   6990    ?
飶   6991    ?
鼟   6992    ?
銟   6993    ?
鵶   6994    ?
箰   7012    ?
阬   7013    ?
耠   7014    ?
錔   7015    ?
騕   7016    ?
鬴   7017    ?
魭   7018    ?
鮔   7019    ?
纆   7036    ?
逴   7037    ?
睰   7038    ?
筜   7039    ?
觾   7040    ?
醳   7041    ?
鎡   7042    ?
鐉   7043    ?
箙   7057    ?
耔   7058    ?
菼   7082    ?
褘   7083    ?
韣   7084    ?
縗   7104    ?
肵   7105    ?
詴   7106    ?
赩   7107    ?
颣   7108    ?
鶂   7109    ?
鼒   7110    ?
稾   7111    ?
蒎   7112    ?
騩   7113    ?
聓   7114    ?
睗   7129    ?
矱   7130    ?
筤   7131    ?
荂   7132    ?
葅   7133    ?
賵   7134    ?
鄏   7135    ?
瀵   7136    ?
霡   7137    ?
霿   7138    ?
韝   7139    ?
酏   7140    ?
穨   7141    ?
鞾   7142    ?
蒒   7143    ?
簉   7165    ?
踶   7166    ?
铘   7167    ?
龏   7168    ?
篘   7169    ?
镋   7170    ?
鮸   7171    ?
繶   7195    ?
諟   7196    ?
踳   7197    ?
鄅   7198    ?
霃   7199    ?
馌   7200    ?
盵   7201    ?
繦   7202    ?
艃   7203    ?
蕆   7204    ?
魞   7205    ?
睮   7231    ?
穠   7232    ?
罳   7233    ?
耏   7234    ?
芣   7235    ?
蟟   7236    ?
詶   7237    ?
醓   7238    ?
錡   7239    ?
馺   7240    ?
鸤   7241    ?
礧   7242    ?
緭   7243    ?
辿   7244    ?
銇   7245    ?
紟   7278    ?
脀   7279    ?
襮   7280    ?
讎   7281    ?
瘃   7282    ?
髢   7283    ?
鍰   7284    ?
睔   7313    ?
穬   7314    ?
罛   7315    ?
翿   7316    ?
脡   7317    ?
鋗   7318    ?
鍭   7319    ?
鹔   7320    ?
磧   7321    ?
荝   7322    ?
釳   7323    ?
隇   7324    ?
縓   7354    ?
蹛   7355    ?
鎛   7356    ?
眴   7357    ?
藊   7358    ?
詽   7359    ?
鮿   7360    ?
糒   7397    ?
紑   7398    ?
臡   7399    ?
虩   7400    ?
蚳   7401    ?
褖   7402    ?
郚   7403    ?
雺   7404    ?
肐   7405    ?
覸   7406    ?
鞉   7407    ?
韠   7408    ?
飡   7409    ?
鴋   7410    ?
稊   7452    ?
籧   7453    ?
紿   7454    ?
蠮   7455    ?
訿   7456    ?
遫   7457    ?
遰   7458    ?
郥   7459    ?
郳   7460    ?
鍉   7461    ?
麷   7462    ?
睶   7463    ?
磵   7464    ?
箄   7465    ?
箻   7466    ?
籟   7467    ?
訍   7468    ?
谸   7469    ?
豽   7470    ?
靽   7471    ?
   7472    ?
眽   7508    ?
綪   7509    ?
缼   7510    ?
腶   7511    ?
讻   7512    ?
輹   7513    ?
桊   7514    ?
餤   7515    ?
饦   7516    ?
鬒   7517    ?
鵩   7518    ?
褍   7519    ?
誗   7520    ?
鏚   7521    ?
碹   7522    ?
葊   7523    ?
瞶   7553    ?
箑   7554    ?
舠   7555    ?
茒   7556    ?
訰   7557    ?
輠   7558    ?
鄴   2454    ?
鄪   7559    ?
闑   7560    ?
霛   7561    ?
馹   7562    ?
鸃   7563    ?
眡   7564    ?
萐   7565    ?
輣   7566    ?
霙   7567    ?
霦   7568    ?
鯌   7569    ?
繍   7570    ?
頧   7571    ?
箎   7612    ?
籝   7613    ?
綧   7614    ?
茪   7615    ?
蓩   7616    ?
藂   7617    ?
虣   7618    ?
輮   7619    ?
蔹   7620    ?
鐕   7621    ?
飂   7622    ?
鱐   7623    ?
稒   7624    ?
篣   7625    ?
艔   7626    ?
蜋   7627    ?
袎   7628    ?
酧   7629    ?
鋘   7630    ?
骦   7631    ?
籛   7683    ?
腒   7684    ?
苨   7685    ?
薶   7686    ?
藋   7687    ?
虆   7688    ?
螉   7689    ?
觕   7690    ?
謻   7691    ?
豝   7692    ?
轙   7693    ?
靬   7694    ?
鞂   7695    ?
鞹   7696    ?
騂   7697    ?
鶅   7698    ?
鷮   7699    ?
鼲   7700    ?
礠   7701    ?
裌   7702    ?
謳   7703    ?
邟   7704    ?
鉟   7705    ?
飻   7706    ?
骭   7707    ?
魹   7708    ?
鼕   7709    ?
铇   7710    ?
簭   7763    ?
縳   7764    ?
繘   7765    ?
荓   7766    ?
蔕   7767    ?
謣   7768    ?
貆   7769    ?
陊   7770    ?
籺   7771    ?
羾   7772    ?
翏   7773    ?
艥   7774    ?
茤   7775    ?
譒   7776    ?
趍   7777    ?
踠   7778    ?
輙   7779    ?
輬   7780    ?
轀   7781    ?
鞕   7782    ?
駴   7783    ?
簖   7784    ?
魶   7785    ?
瞾   7845    ?
笵   7846    ?
綆   7847    ?
縰   7848    ?
罻   7849    ?
罿   7850    ?
翽   7851    ?
艓   7852    ?
蝃   7853    ?
諰   7854    ?
蹜   7855    ?
蹝   7856    ?
蹢   7857    ?
韔   7858    ?
騵   7859    ?
齍   7860    ?
箶   7861    ?
縌   7862    ?
莝   7863    ?
諐   7864    ?
諕   7865    ?
跀   7866    ?
迱   7867    ?
鞀   7868    ?
饠   7869    ?
鸜   7870    ?
禂   7919    ?
篹   7920    ?
簁   7921    ?
緪   7922    ?
胏   7923    ?
膍   7924    ?
蓻   7925    ?
袙   7926    ?
誀   7927    ?
譣   7928    ?
鄋   7929    ?
鉥   7930    ?
鞙   7931    ?
鞸   7932    ?
韇   7933    ?
駓   7934    ?
駪   7935    ?
驒   7936    ?
驔   7937    ?
魠   7938    ?
鵫   7939    ?
鸐   7940    ?
綷   7941    ?
緃   7942    ?
艅   7943    ?
艛   7944    ?
葧   7945    ?
輄   7946    ?
迾   7947    ?
鋄   7948    ?
雭   7949    ?
顡   7950    ?
砅   8024    ?
硰   8025    ?
祴   8026    ?
竁   8027    ?
箮   8028    ?
罦   8029    ?
羋   8030    ?
耾   8031    ?
膇   8032    ?
芀   8033    ?
蕫   8034    ?
蚔   8035    ?
蚼   8036    ?
衺   8037    ?
觡   8038    ?
豻   8039    ?
貜   8040    ?
跇   8041    ?
輷   8042    ?
轊   8043    ?
轛   8044    ?
郰   8045    ?
鐢   8046    ?
鞢   8047    ?
頀   8048    ?
驓   8049    ?
鳲   8050    ?
鷤   8051    ?
黅   8052    ?
睌   8053    ?
矏   8054    ?
硠   8055    ?
秪   8056    ?
窐   8057    ?
綉   8058    ?
纊   8059    ?
羓   8060    ?
虄   8061    ?
蜄   8062    ?
衊   8063    ?
衵   8064    ?
賝   8065    ?
辷   8066    ?
霌   8067    ?
颿   8068    ?
馎   8069    ?
騳   8070    ?
鵕   8071    ?
   8072    ?
瞤   8073    ?
瞮   8074    ?
螱   8075    ?
馡   8076    ?
稏   8153    ?
竫   8154    ?
簮   8155    ?
粬   8156    ?
萭   8157    ?
蔇   8158    ?
薉   8159    ?
蘀   8160    ?
衃   8161    ?
詡   8162    ?
謞   8163    ?
譺   8164    ?
跦   8165    ?
軶   8166    ?
輤   8167    ?
轞   8168    ?
迲   8169    ?
遻   8170    ?
邧   8171    ?
郲   8172    ?
鄁   8173    ?
鄎   8174    ?
醷   8175    ?
釚   8176    ?
鈷   8177    ?
颒   8178    ?
驐   8179    ?
鮆   8180    ?
鰋   8181    ?
鵙   8182    ?
   8183    ?
   8184    ?
眂   8185    ?
眻   8186    ?
矴   8187    ?
硥   8188    ?
硿   8189    ?
碨   8190    ?
祡   8191    ?
秄   8192    ?
笯   8193    ?
箵   8194    ?
綇   8195    ?
臽   8196    ?
蒦   8197    ?
蜯   8198    ?
訬   8199    ?
跕   8200    ?
鉾   8201    ?
銂   8202    ?
鍌   8203    ?
顤   8204    ?
饢   8205    ?
魦   8206    ?
鯑   8207    ?
鴬   8208    ?
鴯   8209    ?
譎   8210    ?
磶   8295    ?
禕   8296    ?
綌   8297    ?
緆   8298    ?
緉   8299    ?
羱   8300    ?
臲   8301    ?
舝   8302    ?
芐   8303    ?
荁   8304    ?
蓽   8305    ?
蟺   8306    ?
裻   8307    ?
觩   8308    ?
謰   8309    ?
譈   8310    ?
讘   8311    ?
谹   8312    ?
趠   8313    ?
跲   8314    ?
郱   8315    ?
銋   8316    ?
銍   8317    ?
闤   8318    ?
禚   8319    ?
騋   8320    ?
騞   8321    ?
鬌   8322    ?
鰱   8323    ?
鳺   8324    ?
鶋   8325    ?
鷞   8326    ?
麌   8327    ?
眑   8328    ?
硋   8329    ?
碆   8330    ?
祄   8331    ?
秖   8332    ?
稥   8333    ?
縖   8334    ?
繈   8335    ?
羫   8336    ?
肹   8337    ?
膸   8338    ?
蕪   8339    ?
蛒   8340    ?
蛠   8341    ?
蛺   8342    ?
褉   8343    ?
覜   8344    ?
觟   8345    ?
譀   8346    ?
譂   8347    ?
蹮   8348    ?
軭   8349    ?
輭   8350    ?
錝   8351    ?
鍙   8352    ?
阹   8353    ?
霔   8354    ?
頟   8355    ?
馯   8356    ?
鮬   8357    ?
鮽   8358    ?
鲺   8359    ?
鴸   8360    ?
鸗   8361    ?
鹺   8362    ?
龕   8363    ?
龥   8364    ?
磏   8365    ?
蚏   8366    ?
穋   8473    ?
簎   8474    ?
簙   8475    ?
粠   8476    ?
紽   8477    ?
綋   8478    ?
繓   8479    ?
罫   8480    ?
聨   8481    ?
胉   8482    ?
荺   8483    ?
莦   8484    ?
菤   8485    ?
葽   8486    ?
藾   8487    ?
蘳   8488    ?
蝚   8489    ?
袾   8490    ?
褟   8491    ?
襴   8492    ?
蹍   8493    ?
邞   8494    ?
鄸   8495    ?
鄾   8496    ?
鋽   8497    ?
霒   8498    ?
韘   8499    ?
飱   8500    ?
餲   8501    ?
饙   8502    ?
饛   8503    ?
駬   8504    ?
駭   8505    ?
骴   8506    ?
鳦   8507    ?
鴶   8508    ?
鶖   8509    ?
鶹   8510    ?
鸋   8511    ?
鸒   8512    ?
硉   8513    ?
礲   8514    ?
紴   8515    ?
羻   8516    ?
耭   8517    ?
艌   8518    ?
蕽   8519    ?
蘴   8520    ?
誷   8521    ?
趭   8522    ?
趲   8523    ?
跴   8524    ?
躀   8525    ?
輺   8526    ?
鄨   8527    ?
鎻   8528    ?
鏬   8529    ?
鑅   8530    ?
鑳   8531    ?
韅   8532    ?
驏   8533    ?
髸   8534    ?
髾   8535    ?
鰦   8536    ?
鵊   8537    ?
鷶   8538    ?
黵   8539    ?
齚   8540    ?
齱   8541    ?
   8542    ?
茙   8543    ?
蟏   8544    ?
鈚   8545    ?
碪   8673    ?
礛   8674    ?
稕   8675    ?
窞   8676    ?
籈   8677    ?
粆   8678    ?
紡   8679    ?
紶   8680    ?
緧   8681    ?
罬   8682    ?
罭   8683    ?
羃   8684    ?
羒   8685    ?
胈   8686    ?
脠   8687    ?
荍   8688    ?
蒩   8689    ?
蕇   8690    ?
蝡   8691    ?
蝯   8692    ?
螔   8693    ?
螮   8694    ?
襡   8695    ?
讔   8696    ?
豦   8697    ?
豵   8698    ?
貕   8699    ?
蹪   8700    ?
軥   8701    ?
迗   8702    ?
鄇   8703    ?
鄵   8704    ?
鎼   8705    ?
鐀   8706    ?
靧   8707    ?
鞆   8708    ?
頄   8709    ?
頖   8710    ?
顠   8711    ?
顭   8712    ?
駧   8713    ?
騤   8714    ?
鬠   8715    ?
魯   8716    ?
鷕   8717    ?
黰   8718    ?
瞚   8719    ?
砆   8720    ?
硜   8721    ?
硾   8722    ?
穭   8723    ?
窙   8724    ?
簂   8725    ?
簛   8726    ?
綕   8727    ?
綘   8728    ?
罎   8729    ?
羛   8730    ?
腇   8731    ?
舺   8732    ?
葓   8733    ?
蓪   8734    ?
蓶   8735    ?
蔪   8736    ?
蘤   8737    ?
蛦   8738    ?
蟕   8739    ?
袯   8740    ?
襂   8741    ?
詃   8742    ?
謌   8743    ?
賿   8744    ?
跧   8745    ?
蹃   8746    ?
軖   8747    ?
迌   8748    ?
逈   8749    ?
鄌   8750    ?
鈗   8751    ?
鈠   8752    ?
銕   8753    ?
錉   8754    ?
鏜   8755    ?
鏾   8756    ?
鐞   8757    ?
锠   8758    ?
閈   8759    ?
隁   8760    ?
鞰   8761    ?
騬   8762    ?
鬺   8763    ?
魌   8764    ?
鮹   8765    ?
鯇   8766    ?
鰶   8767    ?
鸕   8768    ?
黸   8769    ?
瞈   8770    ?
稐   8771    ?
蘐   8772    ?
衏   8773    ?
趂   8774    ?
酕   8775    ?
釸   8776    ?
魀   8777    ?
眧   8925    ?
瞉   8926    ?
砠   8927    ?
硩   8928    ?
磌   8929    ?
礆   8930    ?
穧   8931    ?
窹   8932    ?
筀   8933    ?
筳   8934    ?
粰   8935    ?
紨   8936    ?
縏   8937    ?
脢   8938    ?
膞   8939    ?
臩   8940    ?
芧   8941    ?
茠   8942    ?
蓤   8943    ?
蔈   8944    ?
薧   8945    ?
蚆   8946    ?
蛁   8947    ?
蛫   8948    ?
蛵   8949    ?
螆   8950    ?
蠉   8951    ?
衱   8952    ?
衶   8953    ?
褮   8954    ?
譆   8955    ?
赬   8956    ?
赸   8957    ?
趻   8958    ?
躠   8959    ?
輲   8960    ?
迧   8961    ?
迶   8962    ?
邚   8963    ?
郔   8964    ?
鄭   8965    ?
醝   8966    ?
鈭   8967    ?
鈲   8968    ?
鋿   8969    ?
鎿   8970    ?
钀   8971    ?
閨   8972    ?
闠   8973    ?
阺   8974    ?
鞁   8975    ?
饁   8976    ?
馲   8977    ?
駠   8978    ?
騉   8979    ?
騝   8980    ?
騲   8981    ?
髱   8982    ?
魧   8983    ?
魪   8984    ?
鯠   8985    ?
鯦   8986    ?
鱁   8987    ?
鴘   8988    ?
鵴   8989    ?
鵽   8990    ?
鶬   8991    ?
鶵   8992    ?
鼁   8993    ?
鼨   8994    ?
矐   8995    ?
硍   8996    ?
硲   8997    ?
磖   8998    ?
礔   8999    ?
礟   9000    ?
禝   9001    ?
稉   9002    ?
穞   9003    ?
窱   9004    ?
笓   9005    ?
粨   9006    ?
羂   9007    ?
翓   9008    ?
腷   9009    ?
茰   9010    ?
蓘   9011    ?
蕯   9012    ?
蘎   9013    ?
蟉   9014    ?
蠞   9015    ?
裞   9016    ?
襒   9017    ?
襯   9018    ?
誧   9019    ?
諅   9020    ?
豲   9021    ?
貃   9022    ?
蹏   9023    ?
軮   9024    ?
軵   9025    ?
轑   9026    ?
銉   9027    ?
銔   9028    ?
銞   9029    ?
銢   9030    ?
鋧   9031    ?
鋲   9032    ?
鍗   9033    ?
弪   9034    ?
鎶   9035    ?
鏋   9036    ?
鐗   9037    ?
鑡   9038    ?
閦   9039    ?
隖   9040    ?
霊   9041    ?
霐   9042    ?
霬   9043    ?
鞐   9044    ?
顇   9045    ?
駦   9046    ?
瘭   9047    ?
骲   9048    ?
鬁   9049    ?
鮐   9050    ?
鯄   9051    ?
鱠   9052    ?
鳸   9053    ?
鵷   9054    ?
鹻   9055    ?
黳   9056    ?
齖   9057    ?
齨   9058    ?
龗   9059    ?
郎   9060    ?
   9061    ?
   9062    ?
矨   9063    ?
筯   9064    ?
糫   9065    ?
苰   9066    ?
蜳   9067    ?
衠   9068    ?
觹   9069    ?
輆   9070    ?
酘   9071    ?
銿   9072    ?
閵   9073    ?
韁   9074    ?
颭   9075    ?
餪   9076    ?
鯾   9077    ?
鱑   9078    ?
麢   9079    ?
矕   9285    ?
碈   9286    ?
竀   9287    ?
篎   9288    ?
籊   9289    ?
籯   9290    ?
籿   9291    ?
絩   9292    ?
緎   9293    ?
緘   9294    ?
縒   9295    ?
繗   9296    ?
翨   9297    ?
聳   9298    ?
肂   9299    ?
脪   9300    ?
腢   9301    ?
膷   9302    ?
荎   9303    ?
菋   9304    ?
菛   9305    ?
葝   9306    ?
蓫   9307    ?
藄   9308    ?
蘦   9309    ?
虤   9310    ?
螇   9311    ?
蟘   9312    ?
蠰   9313    ?
袡   9314    ?
裧   9315    ?
褞   9316    ?
覑   9317    ?
覕   9318    ?
訧   9319    ?
諗   9320    ?
謍   9321    ?
譐   9322    ?
讇   9323    ?
跠   9324    ?
軜   9325    ?
輢   9326    ?
邍   9327    ?
邤   9328    ?
郠   9329    ?
鋱   9330    ?
錀   9331    ?
錇   9332    ?
鍘   9333    ?
鏄   9334    ?
阞   9335    ?
陑   9336    ?
陒   9337    ?
牮   9338    ?
雈   9339    ?
雴   9340    ?
顈   9341    ?
駫   9342    ?
駽   9343    ?
騢   9344    ?
騱   9345    ?
驋   9346    ?
鬵   9347    ?
魩   9348    ?
魷   9349    ?
鮦   9350    ?
鯉   9351    ?
鯷   9352    ?
鰢   9353    ?
鱨   9354    ?
鼽   9355    ?
鴠   9356    ?
鴩   9357    ?
鵔   9358    ?
鵻   9359    ?
鶉   9360    ?
鶌   9361    ?
鶛   9362    ?
鸅   9363    ?
麔   9364    ?
鼣   9365    ?
齵   9366    ?
睳   9367    ?
矓   9368    ?
矖   9369    ?
砎   9370    ?
砙   9371    ?
砞   9372    ?
碄   9373    ?
祽   9374    ?
禶   9375    ?
秈   9376    ?
穅   9377    ?
穾   9378    ?
窛   9379    ?
窡   9380    ?
笒   9381    ?
筟   9382    ?
箺   9383    ?
綁   9384    ?
緾   9385    ?
縸   9386    ?
繠   9387    ?
繥   9388    ?
繰   9389    ?
罉   9390    ?
罏   9391    ?
羍   9392    ?
翋   9393    ?
翝   9394    ?
舥   9395    ?
舼   9396    ?
艗   9397    ?
菈   9398    ?
菗   9399    ?
菷   9400    ?
蓜   9401    ?
蔮   9402    ?
蕢   9403    ?
藔   9404    ?
藸   9405    ?
虉   9406    ?
虦   9407    ?
螄   9408    ?
蠁   9409    ?
衜   9410    ?
袏   9411    ?
袹   9412    ?
襗   9413    ?
襵   9414    ?
覔   9415    ?
諞   9416    ?
謫   9417    ?
謭   9418    ?
譡   9419    ?
譮   9420    ?
豮   9421    ?
貀   9422    ?
賶   9423    ?
賽   9424    ?
赥   9425    ?
跿   9426    ?
踑   9427    ?
躃   9428    ?
軯   9429    ?
轒   9430    ?
邜   9431    ?
鄈   9432    ?
釄   9433    ?
釗   9434    ?
鈓   9435    ?
鈳   9436    ?
鉌   9437    ?
鉡   9438    ?
鉧   9439    ?
銚   9440    ?
鋠   9441    ?
鍖   9442    ?
鍞   9443    ?
鎁   9444    ?
鎫   9445    ?
鏠   9446    ?
鐈   9447    ?
鐝   9448    ?
鐫   9449    ?
鐶   9450    ?
鑬   9451    ?
鑻   9452    ?
镼   9453    ?
隑   9454    ?
隞   9455    ?
靫   9456    ?
鞜   9457    ?
韯   9458    ?
颽   9459    ?
飜   9460    ?
飹   9461    ?
餭   9462    ?
駖   9463    ?
駻   9464    ?
驉   9465    ?
髐   9466    ?
髨   9467    ?
鬊   9468    ?
鬜   9469    ?
鮚   9470    ?
鯱   9471    ?
鰑   9472    ?
鰣   9473    ?
鶀   9474    ?
鷯   9475    ?
鷻   9476    ?
鷾   9477    ?
鸝   9478    ?
黚   9479    ?
黦   9480    ?
鼚   9481    ?
鼝   9482    ?
齃   9483    ?
齘   9484    ?
齴   9485    ?
龣   9486    ?
眤   9487    ?
礵   9488    ?
窵   9489    ?
筓   9490    ?
籖   9491    ?
縴   9492    ?
翲   9493    ?
膁   9494    ?
菾   9495    ?
萠   9496    ?
薈   9497    ?
蟇   9498    ?
蠧   9499    ?
觺   9500    ?
鍾   9501    ?
駾   9502    ?
鴏   9503    ?
   9504    ?
鴒   9804    ?
盷   9805    ?
眿   9806    ?
硯   9807    ?
硻   9808    ?
稯   9809    ?
稰   9810    ?
筿   9811    ?
篞   9812    ?
簲   9813    ?
籡   9814    ?
糔   9815    ?
絖   9816    ?
髃   3638    ?
繛   9817    ?
繡   9818    ?
罊   9819    ?
翪   9820    ?
肬   9821    ?
胻   9822    ?
脄   9823    ?
膉   9824    ?
芛   9825    ?
芺   9826    ?
茥   9827    ?
茦   9828    ?
菎   9829    ?
菺   9830    ?
萴   9831    ?
萶   9832    ?
葐   9833    ?
葒   9834    ?
葥   9835    ?
蒚   9836    ?
蒤   9837    ?
蒰   9838    ?
蓲   9839    ?
蔏   9840    ?
蔜   9841    ?
蔩   9842    ?
蕀   9843    ?
蕭   9844    ?
蕸   9845    ?
薕   9846    ?
藆   9847    ?
藲   9848    ?
蘜   9849    ?
蘱   9850    ?
蘵   9851    ?
蚅   9852    ?
蜤   9853    ?
蜬   9854    ?
蜰   9855    ?
蠀   9856    ?
蠑   9857    ?
蠦   9858    ?
蠯   9859    ?
蠸   9860    ?
衈   9861    ?
袲   9862    ?
袸   9863    ?
袺   9864    ?
裷   9865    ?
襋   9866    ?
覄   9867    ?
詌   9868    ?
諵   9869    ?
謘   9870    ?
謼   9871    ?
譥   9872    ?
谺   9873    ?
貥   9874    ?
贙   9875    ?
踒   9876    ?
踕   9877    ?
躆   9878    ?
輁   9879    ?
輱   9880    ?
轃   9881    ?
迊   9882    ?
迬   9883    ?
遧   9884    ?
鄥   9885    ?
鄻   9886    ?
鈏   9887    ?
銈   9888    ?
銖   9889    ?
鋯   9890    ?
鍠   9891    ?
鏌   9892    ?
閞   9893    ?
陭   9894    ?
隒   9895    ?
隿   9896    ?
靲   9897    ?
鞇   9898    ?
鞈   9899    ?
韙   9900    ?
韾   9901    ?
頲   9902    ?
飄   9903    ?
餕   9904    ?
餰   9905    ?
饓   9906    ?
馽   9907    ?
駩   9908    ?
駯   9909    ?
鰝   9910    ?
鰭   9911    ?
鱦   9912    ?
鵃   9913    ?
鵅   9914    ?
鵌   9915    ?
鵛   9916    ?
鵵   9917    ?
鶔   9918    ?
鶞   9919    ?
鶤   9920    ?
鷬   9921    ?
麍   9922    ?
麙   9923    ?
黕   9924    ?
鼵   9925    ?
謯   9926    ?
睜   9927    ?
瞝   9928    ?
矆   9929    ?
矠   9930    ?
磘   9931    ?
磤   9932    ?
```

Comment: Good job. A lot of fun statistics can be done on the lists :)

Answer (score -2):

I think you should think about there are two sets of Chinese charaters. In Hongkong, Taiwan and some Chinese communities in the UK, US, traditional Chinese charaters are still used; whereas people on mainland China use simplified Chinese charaters. Here there is a traditional Chinese word, 後, which may mean "behind" and the word 后 means "queen". In simplified Chinese, 後 is replaced by 后 and hence Chinese in China may not know 後 and think it is an obsolescent word but Chinese in other regions are still using it.

Comment: Question is about Classical (文言) vs Modern (国语／普通话), _not_ Traditional （繁体) vs Simplified (简体)